# Change color of a list of string - Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, gesturedetector

I have a list of string, and i want to change the color when i tap on one of them,
Here is my code so far :

```
  var list = ["name", "city", "country", "email"];


appBar: AppBar(
    title:Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: List.generate(4, (index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Text(
                  list[index],
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () {},
            );
          }),
        ),
      
  ),
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Can you please tell whether you are using a stateful widget or stateless widget?

Comment: stateful widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering it is a stateful widget you can do this as follows:

```
var list = ["name", "city", "country", "email"];
List <int>tapped = [];

appBar: AppBar(
    title:Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: List.generate(4, (index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Text(
                  list[index],
                  style: TextStyle(color: tapped.contains(index) ? Colors.red : Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                if(tapped.contains(index)){
                  this.setState(() {tapped.remove(index);});
                } else {
                  this.setState(() {tapped.add(index);});
                }
              },
            );
          }),
        ),
      
  ),
```

Comment: This is what i did, and it works for me, 
add a variable int selectedIndex;  then int TextStyle(color : selectedIndex == index ? Colors.red : Colors.blue , and a setState ((){ selectedIndex = index;  })

Comment: Yeah. I thought that colors of the selected texts should remain selected until they are unselected. But if you want that they should be automatically unselected if another color is selected, then that is okay! It is just a matter of what you want. As it was not mentioned in the question, I did what appeared you wanted.